# Sequential File Access, load multiple text files in project directory using C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to load multiple files from a project directory. For example, loading FileA.txt, FileB.txt, and FileC.txt from a folder (raw/assets) within the project folder?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you automatically want to load all files in a directory, without knowing their names or number before-hand?

Comment: I apologize for not being more specific. I want to read the contents of multiple text files within a directory without knowing the amount of files. The files would all contain the same prefix. There could be 1 or 100 files. I am successfully able to open multiple files given I know the amount. I want to know how I could "scan" for the amount of files, read 1, then jump to the next file. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Directory handling is system-specific.  What system are you on, and what libraries are you able to use (e.g. Boost, Qt)?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 machine. This is for a class project. I am not aware of any libraries we are allowed or not allowed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your comment says you're targetting Windows, take a look at this API function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx

Find files matching your pattern and deal with them

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/